# Necessary to use a checksum on a backup and not solely the 'verify backup' option?

Tags: sql-server, backup

If want to ensure the integrity of a backup, would it be a necessity to use a checksum on all of my backups and not just the 'verify backup' option?

Comment: Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189587(v=sql.105).aspx) it appears as though 'verify backup' ensures that the set is restore-able whereas the checksum indicates more about the data within the backup.

Comment: That's perfect, much appreciated, swascheck.

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)

> CHECKSUM Specifies that the backup operation will verify each page for
>   checksum and torn page, if enabled and available, and generate a
>   checksum for the entire backup. This is the default behavior for a
>   compressed backup.

All the verify backup option does is confirm that the header of your backup is readable, nothing else.

Neither of these options will tell you that you have a good backup! The only way to confirm that your backup is good is to restore it on another system